# JQuery selector affects its child

Tags: jquery

How can I make the Jquery code select only the main div(.post)?
It also affects it's child, the inside div.

I'm using this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( ".post" )
    .mouseover(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            height: 180,
            width: 160
        }, 200, function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            height: 150,
            width: 150
        }, 200, function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });
```

});

Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/q5g4xrqf/

Comment: doesn't effect the inner element for me (firefox 37) browser issue maybe?

Comment: When you roll the mouse over the orange div, it grows, ok!
But when you're inside the orange one and rolls over the black on, it shrinks and grows back again... :/

Comment: So, I updated and got here: http://jsfiddle.net/q5g4xrqf/5/

And I want a text to appear in the top of the orange div, but I don't want the black div to move. What's the best solution?

Here's how it is: http://jsfiddle.net/q5g4xrqf/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch your `.mouseover()` and `.mouseout()` for `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".post")
        .mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: 180,
            width: 160
        }, 200, function () {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    })
        .mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: 150,
            width: 150
        }, 200, function () {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/q5g4xrqf/1/)**

From the docs:

> The mouseenter/mouseleave event differs from mouseover/mouseout in the way it handles
>   event bubbling. The mouseenter/mouseleave event only triggers its handler when
>   the mouse enters/leaves the element it is bound to, not a descendant.

Note also that you could also shorten the code a little by using the [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function which calls mouseenter and mouseleave.

Comment: It worked! THANKS!
I have to wait 6 minutes to accept here... :/ and 15 rep to make an upvote

Answer (score 0):

The `mouseover` and `mouseout` are doing their function here. Use `hover` to counter this effect.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q5g4xrqf/2/)**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.post').hover(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: 180,
            width: 160
        }, 200, function () {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    }, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: 150,
            width: 150
        }, 200, function () {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :** use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

**Reason :* As stated by the [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/#entry-examples), `mouseover` and `mouseout` bubble into child elements :

> `mouseover` fires when the pointer moves into the child element as well, while `mouseenter` fires only when the pointer moves into the bound element.

It is the same thing for `mouseout` and `mouseleave`.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/q5g4xrqf/3/